# No Processed matches the given query,Pk returning weird errors?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, primary-key

I'm working on a Django project where users can add patients and patients can have images uploaded by users and these images can have processed images.

so I made a list view has a simple detail view containing the patient data and the uploaded images but whenever I try making a navigation link to the processed images I get weird errors like

> No Processed matches the given query

and

> Reverse for 'result' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['patients/result/(?P[0-9]+)$']

and when i enter the link manully There's no images appear nor any html tags just the inherited template and nothing from the actual page, and to keep in mind I render the processed images the same way that the uploaded images is rendered but both of them isn't similar in how are they refered to in the admin as one of them is assigned by path.

The first is uploaded by a normal form and the second is assigned by a function that returns a path.

[image: The analyzed image]

[image: The uploaded image]

## models.py

```
class UploadedImages(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient,
on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='images')
    pre_analysed =  models.ImageField(upload_to = user_directory_path ,  verbose_name = 'Image')

class Processed(models.Model):
    uploaded_image = models.ForeignKey(UploadedImages,
on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='processed')
    analysedimage = models.ImageField(upload_to=analyses_directory_path,blank=True)
```

## views.py

```
def ResultDetails(request, pk=None):
    result = get_object_or_404(models.Processed,pk=pk)
    context = {
        'result' : result
    }
    template = "patients/album.html"
    return render(request,template,context)
```

## template

```
{% if Patient_detail.images %}
 <div class="row">
                                         {% for image in Patient_detail.images.all %}
                 <div class="col-md-4 img-box">
                     <div class="card">
                        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                    <a href="{{ image.pre_analysed.url }}" data-lightbox="patient's images" >
                        <img src="{{ image.pre_analysed.url }}" class="img-thumbnail" >
                    </a>
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                              <div class="btn-group">
                                  <a href="{% url 'patients:analyse_images' image.pk %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Analyse</a>
                                  <a href="{% url 'patients:result' image.pk %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Result</a>
                                  <button type ="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal"
                                          data-target="#modalDelete1{{ image.pk }}">Delete</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
    {% else %}
<p>no images to show yet!</p>
{% endif %}
```

in the template I tried `pk=image.pk` and `image.processed.pk` and that last one returned the second error. I really appreciate any help could be give because I've been stuck on this for a good while now.
Adding the code snippets now.

Comment: What is `Patient_detail.images`?

Comment: Also, please don't use Capital names for variables and functions. As per Python conventions, Capital names should only be used for classes whereas variable and function names should start with a small letter. It gets really hard to read the code if you don't stick to the conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are not weird. The first one tells you, that there doesn't exist any `Processed` objects, that matches the query constraints (eg. the error would come if you did `Processed.objects.get(pk=7)` but didn't have any `Processed` objects with a `pk` of 7). This must stem from somewhere else than your `ResultDetails` view, since this calls `get_object_or_404`.

The second error tells you, that the url Django is trying to create with `reverse` has no match in `urls`, when it is supplied with an empty argument. So, somehow you're parsing an empty string as an argument to `"patients:result"` somewhere.

In your template, you try to create the url by passing `image.processed.pk` as argument. However, the relation between `Processed` and `UploadedImages` is a `ManyToOne`, where one `UploadedImages` object may be related to many `Processed` objects. The call to `image.processed` then gives you all these objects via a `RelatedManager`, which is why `image.processed.pk` doesn't yield a valid argument for `"patients:result"`.

Depending on what you want, you could loop through the objects of `image.processed` or maybe just default to the first instance:

```py
{% url 'patienst:result' image.processed.first.pk %}
```

This would give you the primary key of the first related `Processed` object to the `image` and create a valid url.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that was really helpful.so now I guess i will make it OneToOne relation but would that affect it significantly?
and why when I enter the url manually i don't get anything but the inherited template although it has a h1 tag at the very first line after the extends tag ?

Comment: Well, that's really hard to answer, when I don't know the architecture or the purpose of your app. But if you only want each `UploadedImages` to be related to one `Processed` then you should use a `OneToOneField`. And I can't say what causes your second problem (I'm not even really sure what you mean).

Comment: now I made the field to OneToOne and it's working fine but the problem with showing the images.
would you like to see the template?
btw even if not thanks really for your help I know it's kinda a newbie mistakes.